# ORDER BY after LEFT JOIN not working in browser but working in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine, left-join

I've read several questions and answers here, but I can't seem to find an appropriate solution to my issue ...

I'll try to be clear enough :

First, my SQL query that I tested in phpmyadmin and it worked as I wanted :

```
SELECT s. *
FROM PERSONNE_UDS p, ETUDIANT e, ENTREPRISE ent, STAGE s
LEFT JOIN PERSONNE_UDS pt ON s.tuteur = pt.id_ens
WHERE p.id_etudiant = s.id_etudiant
AND s.id_etudiant = e.id_etudiant
AND ent.id_entreprise = s.id_entreprise
AND p.code_dept =4
AND s.code_per_cal = '2016s2'
AND s.id_formation = 'SC40'
AND s.id_up =2
```

I added :

```
ORDER BY pt.nom ;
```

And in my model class I transformed it like that :

```
$q = $this
->createQuery()
->select('s.*')
->from('Stage s')
->addFrom('PersonneUds p')
->addFrom('Etudiant e')
->addFrom('Entreprise ent') 
->leftJoin('PersonneUds pt ON s.tuteur = pt.id_ens')
->where('p.id_etudiant = s.id_etudiant')
->addWhere('s.id_etudiant = e.id_etudiant')
->addWhere('ent.id_entreprise = s.id_entreprise');
if(is_array($dept)){
  $q->andWhereIn('p.code_dept', $dept);
} else if($dept != -1){
  $q->andWhere('p.code_dept = ?', $dept);
}
$q->addWhere('s.code_per_cal = ?', $code_per_cal)
->addWhere('s.id_formation = ?', $id_formation)
->addWhere('s.id_up = ?', $id_up);



switch ($order_columns){
  case 'nom':
    $q->orderBy('p.nom '.$order_type);
    break;
  case 'entreprise':
    $q->orderBy('ent.nom '.$order_type);
    break;
  case 'sujet':
    $q->orderBy('s.intitule_stage '.$order_type);
    break;
  case 'tuteur':
    //$q->orderBy('s.tuteur '.$order_type);
    $q->orderBy('pt.nom '.$order_type);
    //$q->orderBy('pt.nom '.$order_type);
    break;
  default:
    $q->orderBy('s.etat_stage '.$order_type);
    $q->orderBy('p.nom DESC');
    break;
}

$q->execute();
```

When I try my app it seems that it manage to do the join but not the order by ...

The app is written in PHP5 with CodeIgniter and Doctrine.

Any ideas ?

Sorry for the long question.

EDIT 23-MAY-2017 : Everything works except for the

```
case 'tuteur':
//$q->orderBy('s.tuteur '.$order_type);
$q->orderBy('pt.nom '.$order_type);
//$q->orderBy('pt.nom '.$order_type);
break;
```

Comment: Have you try to store your sql code to a variable? ex: `$sql`. Then do in model: `$this->db->query( $sql )`. It's easy enough instead we make active record for ci.

Comment: I didn't try that because the app is very big and I wanted to be consistent in the way of how the queries are built, but I'll try and I let you know if it works and in that case I'll do this because I've wasted enough time :)

Comment: This way seems to work if i do it in my controller class but that's not the way I want it to work ... in my model class I can't use $this->db ....

Comment: Make sure you have load `database` library on `config/autoload.php`.

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','droits','fonctions','pagination');

Comment: Hmm... seems like OK. how is the result?

Comment: Sorry to reply that late, I'm currently working on other bugs as I can't seem to get rid of this one ... if you have any other ideas I take them.

Comment: OK, let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter active record should be as folow:

```
$q->order_by('column', 'ASC');
```

Comment: I'm testing if it changes something ... I let you know in any case.

EDIT : It doesn't change anything apart from being more readable when you look at the code ...